# values.map is not a function n reactjs while passing array in state and mapping the current state

Tags: reactjs, function, dictionary, react-hooks, state

I have passed an array of objects in useState hook as the initial state and i want to iterate over it using map method in other component, i have passed the current state as prop in the other object and have used map method over it but console message still shows values.map is not a function, i know we can only use map method on array i have done that only still the error shows.

created state and passed an array of objects-

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState([
    {
      name: "Vansh",
      age: 22,
      email: "vansh@gmail.com",
    },
  ]);
```

Passed values as props in Home component-

```
<Home
                addFormData={addFormData}
                setAddFormData={setAddFormData}
                values={values}
                setValues={setValues}
              />
```

Code of my home component-

```
const Home = ({ values }) => {   return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {values.map((val, index) => (
            <tr>
              <td key={val.index}>{val.name}</td>
              <td key={val.index}>{val.age}</td>
              <td key={val.index}>{val.email}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <Link to="/form">
        <button>FORM</button>
      </Link>
    </div>   ); };
```

Comment: This looks right tbh. have you tried debugging {values} ? Remove the {values.map... code entirely, and change it to {console.log(values)} and see what is coming into the component.

Comment: Hopefully it will illustrate at the console if it is indeed an array. fwiw, values isn't a great variable name as it might collide with some other internal object of the same name, maybe try changing your prop name in the off chance this is happening.

Comment: the best part is it is showing in console.log but as soon as i map it the whole table disappears @Squiggs. I also changed prop name to student from values anyways thanx for the try buddy

Comment: Try mapping data with default value it should work for you. i.e { values = [] } or you can try
(values || []).map(() => {})

Comment: @rohan - can I assume that you aren't calling setState anywhere, i.e. state is definitely hard coded, because, if it aint, then you've likely got a situation where you should wait for the array length before looping

e.g.
values && values.length && values.map

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code it's working fine export below your missing export.

```
 const Home = ({ values }) => {
  // console.log(values);
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {values.map((val, index) => (
            <tr>
              <td key={val.index}>{val.name}</td>
              <td key={val.index}>{val.age}</td>
              <td key={val.index}>{val.email}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Please see the code [SandBoxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-surf-c5sgjy?file=/src/components/Home.js)